# unity and audio : how to handle multiple audios

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio

I need your help please , it is about Audio(I'm kinda new to it) . I have some trouble to decide between "loading to memory" and "stream from disk" .

I have like 13 Ai's that will be speaking small sentences ,at time, depending on the event that happens in the game. 
sentences like "OMG!!" , "nohooo why me ?", "please wait". "did you just ..?" etc....

Also , since these audio depends on "events" , some of them might never be used/called during a game session .
(I'll have like more than 150 small audios or voices.. )

- I want to use wav audio files for the voices and i'm developing for mobile 
  I know that streaming from disk is fast but i have heard that it affects performances ... on the other side loading into memory is fast but costly (like 10 minutes consumes like 100MB of memory ).. So i don't know which solution is acceptable for mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel streaming from disk is good enough. I Have been using it for a while and it never gave me performance issues .Unless it does you should not consider the memory trade off.

> Also , since these audio depends on "events" , some of them might
>   never be used/called during a game session

One more reason to stream it.